# Combine two single responses RXSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have two Single values that contain an array of the same object. I want to merge them and apply the map and return them as a Single. Is it possible?

So I have this:

```swift
func fetchTripList(type: TripType) -> Single<[Trip]> {
    let response: Single<APITripListResponse> = request(target: TripsAPI.fetchUpcomingTripList)
    return response.map { $0.toModel() }
}
```

And I need something like this:

```swift
func fetchTripList(type: TripType) -> Single<[Trip]> {
    let responseUpcoming: Single<APITripListResponse> = request(target: TripsAPI.fetchUpcomingTripList)
    let responsePast: Single<APITripListResponse> = request(target: TripsAPI.fetchPastTripList)
    //'Declare a Singe variable <[Trip]> called X merge both responseUpcoming and responsePast, apply to them map { $0.toModel() } and return it'

    return X
}
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried `Observable.merge(responseUpcoming, responsePast).map { $0.toModel() }`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If think `merge` operator is exactly what you want, it will wait until you get data from both of your requests, and then it will merge them into one array, which you can modify with `map`. And after that you can convert it to the `single`.

So it looks like that:

```
Observable.merge(responseUpcoming.asObservable(), responsePast.asObservable()).map { $0.toModel() }.asSingle()
```

Comment: I've edited answer (forgot to convert them to observables), hope this will help you

Comment: what's the difference between this and concat?

Comment: I tried like this: 
let firstSingle = Single<[Int]>.create { observer in
    observer(.success([1]))
    return Disposables.create()
}
let secondSingle = Single<[Int]>.create { observer in
    observer(.success([4, 5, 6]))
    return Disposables.create()
}
Observable<[Int]>.merge(firstSingle.asObservable(), secondSingle.asObservable())
    .asSingle()
    .subscribe(onSuccess: { value in
        print("Single value: \(value)")
    }, onFailure: { error in
        print("Single Error: \(error)")
    })

But it is raised Single Error: Sequence contains more than one element